# Scaling div width with

Tags: css, scale

I have a video and a chat window and I'd like the video (green) to scale up/down in size with the browser. The Chat (red) should stay the same width and stay fixed to the right with a small margin of 25px between them.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Screen shot:

[image: Desired layout]

Here's a screenshot of my code (it won't let me paste it in here for some reason): 
http://www.evernote.com/shard/s321/sh/2ed5d114-5cde-4104-8a85-fb6b62babbd2/a9de27520e13d21b39bf9bb90e439985

Comment: We can't help you without seeing your current code.

Comment: Hi Mooseman. I added my code via screenshot. It won't let me paste in even with the code view thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
#live-video-div{
  float:left;
  width: calc(100% - 275px);
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: green;
}
#chat-div{
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 0 0 25px;
  background: red;
}
```

Demo: http://www.cssdesk.com/59B2G

Comment: Thanks Mooseman! I actually had this same solution but had a mistake in the chat-div float.. dohhh!!